# Monotonic mapping from one-dimensional manifold M to R - What is the order on M?

Tags: functions, manifolds, foliations

First a bit of background: I have a particular $C^1$ codimension one foliation $\mathscr{F}$ of $P$ (n-dimensional Euclidean space with all positive coordinates) which I have equipped with a total order on the leaves. I know that the leaf space $\mathscr{L}$ is a one-dimensional manifold and, because of the type of foliation, I also know that the leaf space  is connected and Hausdorff. I'd like to be able to demonstrate that the canonical projection onto $\mathscr{L}$ can be treated as if it is a map into $R_+$ (strictly positive real line) which respects the order on the leaves.

So I've been researching this and came across the following: In "Geometric Theory of Foliations" by Camacho and Lins Neto there is the statement "...on a simply connected, one-dimensional manifold [I'll call it $M$] (Hausdorff or not) there always exists a continuous, strictly monotonic function". Fine. My question is: Doesn't monotonicity require that there be an order on the domain? If so then what order is on $M$? My suspicion is that we know (by classification of 1-manifolds) that there is a homeomorphism of $\mathscr{L}$ and $R_+$, and we can get an order on each local chart, but it's not global. Is there a result that says if a map is locally monotonic then it's globally so?

I just want to make sure I'm thinking correctly, thank you.

Comment: I suspect that the global order is induced from the local ones by the fact that the derivatives of the change of maps all have the same sign. If I read correctly the question, your manifold is $\mathcal C^1$.

Comment: I see, what you say certainly makes sense. As far as the manifold M I'm not sure, it is the leaf space of a C^1 manifold though. Unfortunately I DON'T know that M is simply connected, but I'll work on it. Thanks for the quick post.

Comment: $M $ may not be simply connected. Look for example to the case of $S^1$.

Comment: Understood; however, the foliation I have is of P, therefore I believe the leaf space is non-compact. Thus, by what I've read of the classification of 1-manifolds, it is homeomorphic to either R or R_+. I'm not sure, but my sense is that will make it simply connected (but admit I could be horribly wrong).